# vue/attribute-hyphenation conflicts with Vue 3.4 same-name shorthand

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, eslint-plugin-vue

In the project I'm working where we have the vue/attribute-hyphenation eslint rule configured to always enforce attribute hyphenation in Vue 3 components. The problem is that the hyphens break the [new Vue 3.4 syntax](https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-3-4#v-bind-same-name-shorthand) to bind attributes to values with the same name.

```
## Works
<my-component :text />
<my-component :myText />

## Doesn't work
<my-component :my-text />
```

I've been trying to make use of the ignore configuration for the rule to include a regex that would ignore the attribute that starts with `:` and does not include `=`. However, I'm wondering if there's a better approach since eslint-plugin-vue already supports some 3.4 according to their [changelog](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/releases/tag/v9.20.0).

This is the rule config in my last attempt:

```
    'vue/attribute-hyphenation': [
      'error',
      'always',
      {
        ignore: ['^:([^=]*)$']
      }
    ],
```

Comment: Rule config looks like it could work, depends on how eslint parses a template. You'll solve it more efficiently in eslint vue repo as it's something that needs the input from the team. But I'd restrain from using :my-text at all, it's ambiguous and it's not documented how normalization rules are applied to value name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the error is coming from eslint? this issue is relevant to vue-language-tools (IDE extension) which was fixed in version 2.0, the latest eslint-plugin-vue shouldnt throw this error, you can find the discussion at
https://github.com/vuejs/language-tools/issues/3830

Comment: If I uninstall Volar in favor of Vue-Official v2.0.5, the error in VSCode goes away, but the component build breaks and does not show up. My test in vitest mounts the component correctly, and updating vue-tsc to 2.0.5 removes the error there so it seems like I need to check why the build is failing. I have `"nuxt": "3.10.2", "vue": "3.4.19"`. I'll try updating dependencies then.

Comment: The component failing to build properly is due to the name change `tiltle` => `my-title`. My bad. It works as expected.